# How should I configure the Sprint in the InputManager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to Player object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent (typeof (BoxCollider))]

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float walkSpeed = 6;
    public float runSpeed = 10;
    public float strafeSpeed = 5;
    public float gravity = 20;
    public float jumpHeight = 2;
    public bool canJump = true;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private bool isGrounded = false;

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return isRunning; }
    }

    void Awake () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        // get correct speed
        float forwardAndBackSpeed = walkSpeed;

        // if running, set run speed
        if (isRunning) {
            forwardAndBackSpeed = runSpeed;
        }

        // calculate how fast it should be moving
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * strafeSpeed, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * forwardAndBackSpeed);
        targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);

        // apply a force that attempts to reach our target velocity
        Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
        Vector3 velocityChange = (targetVelocity - velocity);
        velocityChange.y = 0;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        // jump
        if (canJump && isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(velocity.x, Mathf.Sqrt(2 * jumpHeight * gravity), velocity.z);
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        // apply gravity
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3 (0, -gravity * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass, 0));
    }

    void Update() {
        // check if the player is touching a surface below them
        checkGrounded();

        // check if the player is running
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint")) {
            isRunning = true;
        }

        // check if the player stops running
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Sprint")) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }

    void checkGrounded() {
        /* ==============
         * REMEMBER
         * ==============
         * If you change the size of the prefab, you may have
         * to change the length of the ray to ensure it hits
         * the ground.
         * 
         * All obstacles/walls/floors must have rigidbodies
         * attached to them. If not, Unity physics may get
         * confused and the player can jump really high
         * when in a corner between 2 walls for example.
         */
        float rayLength = 0.7f;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
        //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * rayLength);
        // if there is something directly below the player
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayLength)) {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }    
}
```

There are some parts in the script it's using "Sprint"
For example:

```
// check if the player is running
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint")) {
            isRunning = true;
        }

        // check if the player stops running
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Sprint")) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
```

But "Spring" is not defined in the editor input:
Edit > Project Settings > Input:

[image: Input Manager]

I can change the size in the Input Manager to 19 and it will duplicate the Cancel so I changed the name to Sprint. But what should be the config for the Sprint ? It's now the Cancel config.

[image: Input Manager]

When running the game I'm getting this exception:

ArgumentException: Input Button Sprint is not setup.
 To change the input settings use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input
PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/My Scripts/Character1/PlayerController.cs:62)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound silly, but did you save your project?  If you save your scene, that is different than saving your project which is where the Project Settings are located.

`File -> Save Scene` (CTRL + S) is different than `File -> Save Project`

Answer (score 0):

So this may be very old but I'm going to respond for those that may still be searching in vain:

When adding or changing an input in input manager to "Sprint". It would cause me an error saying it was not set up even if I placed correct naming conventions for every positive or negative button even the alts.

The only fix was to change the name from "Sprint" to "Run" or just about anything works except for "Sprint" for whatever crazy Unity reason there is. Hope this helps those that have been going insane like I did when I first encountered this.